# Running cronjob in the odd-numbered days

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm currently running my MySQL backup script on every day of the week:

```
0 1 * * 1 sh /root/mysql_monday.sh
0 1 * * 2 sh /root/mysql_tuesday.sh
0 1 * * 3 sh /root/mysql_wednesday.sh
0 1 * * 4 sh /root/mysql_thursday.sh
0 1 * * 5 sh /root/mysql_friday.sh
0 1 * * 6 sh /root/mysql_saturday.sh
0 1 * * 0 sh /root/mysql_sunday.sh
```

Now I would like to keep backups for one week more so two weeks in total just to be more secure.

For example: I though I can create one backup file on monday in the even days and then again in the odd-numbered days.

For even days I can just use:

```
0 1 */2 * 1 sh /root/mysql_monday_even.sh
0 1 */2 * 2 sh /root/mysql_tuesday_even.sh
0 1 */2 * 3 sh /root/mysql_wednesday_even.sh
0 1 */2 * 4 sh /root/mysql_thursday_even.sh
0 1 */2 * 5 sh /root/mysql_friday_even.sh
0 1 */2 * 6 sh /root/mysql_saturday_even.sh
0 1 */2 * 0 sh /root/mysql_sunday_even.sh
```

But what about the odd-numbered days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it my way ;)

```
0 1 1,15,29 * * sh /root/mysql_monday.sh
0 1 2,16,30 * * sh /root/mysql_tuesday.sh
0 1 3,17,31 * * sh /root/mysql_wednesday.sh
0 1 4,18 * * sh /root/mysql_thursday.sh
0 1 5,19 * * sh /root/mysql_friday.sh
0 1 6,20 * * sh /root/mysql_saturday.sh
0 1 7,21 * * sh /root/mysql_sunday.sh
0 1 8,22 * * sh /root/mysql_monday2.sh
0 1 9,23 * * sh /root/mysql_tuesday2.sh
0 1 10,24 * * sh /root/mysql_wednesday2.sh
0 1 11,25 * * sh /root/mysql_thursday2.sh
0 1 12,26 * * sh /root/mysql_friday2.sh
0 1 13,27 * * sh /root/mysql_saturday2.sh
0 1 14,28 * * sh /root/mysql_sunday2.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this on unix.stackexchange:

> The syntax you tried is actually ambigous. Depending on how many days
> are in the month, some months it will run on odd days and some on
> even. This is because the way it is calculated takes the total number
> of posibilities and divides them up. You can over-ride this strage-ish
> behavior by manually specifying the day range and using either an odd
> or even number of days. Since even day scripts would never run on the
> 31st day of longer months, you don't loose anything using 30 days as
> the base for even-days, and by specifying specifically to divide it up
> as if there were 31 days you can force odd-day execution.
>
> The syntax would look like this:
>
> Will only run on odd days: `0 0 1-31/2 * * command`
>
> Will only run on even days: `0 0 0-30/2 * * command`
>
> Your concern about months not having the same number of days is not important here
> because no months have MORE days than this and for poor February, the
> date range just won't ever match the last day or two, but it will do
> no harm having it listed.

Source: [Odd/Even Cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/how-can-i-tell-cron-to-run-a-command-every-other-day-odd-even)

Comment: I need 14 different files. This is just for two files.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a better solution would just be to use a proper MySQL backup script designed for weekly, monthly, yearly retention?

Automysqlbackup should work just perfect.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

Comment: No, I'm using my tar+ssh script and I send copy on fly to my backup server.

Answer (score -3):

Crontab generator

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php